# Does C# have array with index is a string like PHP?

Tags: c#, php, arrays, indexing

I have been learning C# myself for 2 months. Before, I learned PHP and see that it has an array where the index is a string, like this:

```
$John["age"] = 21;
$John["location"] = "Vietnam";
```

It is very useful to remember what we set to an array element. I tried to find if C# supports that array type, but I haven't seen any answers, yet.

Does C# have an array like this? If it does, how can I create it?

Comment: FYI, this is called an associative array.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# supports any type of object for an index. A baked-in implementation is `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<T1,T2>`. You can declare one like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Comment: You don't have to use `Add()` to add items - assigning them like in the PHP sample adds them as well.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is an associative array, represented in C# by the generic [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class or the non-generic [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx).

Your code would be only possible with a `Hashmap` as the values are not all of the same type. However, I strongly suggest you re-think that design.

Comment: Would the downvoter please be so kind to comment on the reason? Otherwise the downvote is pointless as I can't improve the answer.

Comment: Hey Daniel, you could technically achieve it with `Dictionary<string, object>`, too. Gains you nothing useful, but you don't *need* a `Hashmap` for that requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<T1,T2>` as other said. To complete your knowledge, you should know that you can control yourself the behavior of the `[]`. Exemple :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string this[string someArg]
    {
        get { return "You called this with " + someArg; }
    }

}

class Program
{

    void Main()
    {
        MyClass x = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine(x["something"]);
    }
}
```

Will produce "You called this with something".

More on this in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Comment: No it is not. A Dictionary is a class, and not a passive array!

Comment: @JvdBerg: Aha. In what way is an array passive? It does boundary checks for example.

Comment: @JvdBerg, in .NET [an array is a class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) as well... even though it has some special properties (e.g. non-fixed size in memory, ability for being casted with co- and contravariance), all arrays are used through a normal object reference to a normal class instance, no magic there.